# Azure B2C: Invite user by email and have them register local account or register with social media account (idP)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm currently busy with creating a custom policy flow where users can only register by invitation. For this I am using a sample policy created by the community https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

This is working perfectly except that I want the user be able to register with  social media (idPs) too. I can't figure out how to to change my custom policy to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern) redirects to an identity provider based on the domain name.

So if the email in the JWT in the invitation is joe@facebook.com it will redirect to the Facebook technical profile to authenticate etc.